# Interface a LCD to RS232

Tags: serial, lcd

Is it possible to connect [this LCD display.](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/SerLCD_V2_5.PDF) Directly to the PC serial port using a **prolific** usb 2 serial converter ?

Comment: More docs (a.o. schematic)  are here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prolific usb to serial converter outputs "TTL-level" signals (that is Transistor-Transistor Logic) and not rs-232 levels, then yes.

Looking around for the prolific adapter you're referencing ([this one](http://prolificusa.com/portfolio/pl2303ta-usb-serial-bridge-controller/)?) it appears that it outputs between 1.8V and 3.3V, which should be able to communicate to the LCD backpack you're looking at.  You really want a chip which outputs from 0 to +5V for communicating with that model, but they also sell the [3.3V model](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9067). I personally use the FTDI ft232rl as my go-to chip of choice for usb to serial converters.

But I digress, if you're only wondering if the display functions taking input from a computer, then the answer is yes.  I did that to test one of those LCDs years ago when I first got it.

Good luck!  Hope that helps.

Comment: How can I see if a serial converter outputs TTL-level signals or RS-232 ? Please teach me

Comment: In general a chip will say on the datasheet that the data output is between ±5 or ±12 volts if it uses rs232 signaling levels.  If it only goes from 0 to +3.3V or from 0 to +5V for the output than it is TTL.

Comment: For example, on the datasheet for the part I sent you Has the table **Table 8-2-2a** which says that the low signal is less than 0.4V (the absolute maximum rating table says no less than -0.3V), and the high signal is greater than 2.4V (the absolute maximum rating table says no greater than 3.6V) so clearly it is TTL, not RS232.

Answer (score 1):

In the schematic you can see that there is no special input circuitry (there is little more than the microcontroller), so you can check the PIC16F88 datasheet for allowed input voltages. When connecting long(ish) wires, I'd advise to use at least a clipping circuit to protect the inputs.

Check Kit Scuzz's answer for the serial converter part. You want to know which voltages it outputs.